# Cant parse JSON with JavaScript and Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

Ive got an PHP which creates a .json file:

```
<?php 

 $data=array( "Name"=>"Someone", "Surname" => "Somebody"); 

 $jsontext = "[";
 foreach($data as $key => $value) {
 $jsontext .= "{objectValue: '".addslashes($key)."', textObject: '".addslashes($value)."'},";
 }
 $jsontext = substr_replace($jsontext, '', -1);
 $jsontext .= "]";

 echo $jsontext;

 $fp = fopen('results.json', 'w');
 fwrite($fp, json_encode($jsontext));
 fclose($fp);
```

?>

This is the results.json:

```
"[{objectValue: 'Name', textObject: 'Someone'},{objectValue: 'Surname', textObject: 'Somebody'}]"
```

The javascript:

```
var xmlHttp = createXmlHttpRequestObject();
var finalText;

window.onload = process;

function createXmlHttpRequestObject() {
var xmlHttp;
if (window.ActiveXObject) {
    try {
        xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    } catch (e) {
        xmlHttp = false;
    }
} else {
    try {
        xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } catch (e) {
        xmlHttp = false;
    }
}
if (!xmlHttp) {
    alert("Cant create XmlHTTP...");
} else {
    return xmlHttp;
}
}


function process() {
if (xmlHttp.readyState == 0 || xmlHttp.readyState == 4) {
    xmlHttp.open("GET", "http://localhost/results.json", true);
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = handleServerResponse;
    xmlHttp.send(null);
} else {
    //setTimeout('process()', 1000);
    alert("Error: Server is busy");
}
}

function handleServerResponse() {
if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200) {
    finalText = xmlHttp.responseText;
}else{
    //alert("Error: server is busy");
}
}


function convertJSON(){
parsedText = JSON.parse(finalText);
alert(parsedText); //This shows the parsed text, it gets here 

document.getElementById('finalResult').innerHTML += parsedText.objectValue;
document.getElementById('finalResult').innerHTML += parsedText.Name;
}
```

Whenever I summon convertJSON from a button onclick I keep getting undefined, when printing the results into the "finalResult" div... what am I doing wrong?

Comment: That's not valid JSON. ***Please*** don't try to build JSON text using string concatenation.

Comment: why don'y you use json_encode?

Comment: @DanielA.White fwrite($fp, json_encode($jsontext)); in the php file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're building your JSON by string concatenation, then sending it into json_encode. Instead build your JSON as an array:

```
$jsonData = array();
foreach($data as $key => $value) {
    $jsonData[] = array('objectValue' => $key, 'textObject' => $value);
}
$jsontext = json_encode($jsonData);
echo $jsontext;
fwrite($fp, $jsontext);
```

Comment: @Alpha2k Just do `json_encode($data)`, you don't really need that loop. And then check with `console.log(parsedText);` what you have exactly.

Comment: the result is [{"objectValue":"Name","textObject":"Someone"},{"objectValue":"Surname","textObject":"Somebody"}] but i cant get anything from that text... i keep getting undefined ffs

Comment: @jeroen The loop is to get the data in the format with objectValue and textObject as keys, it's not really needed, but removing it would require changing the javascript side.

Comment: @Alpha2k The undefined error seems to be in your javascript. parsedText is an array of values, so you probably need parsedText[0].objectValue

Comment: @khartnett The javascript-side doesn't work anyway, so why complicate things :-)

Comment: Good Point @jeroen, Alpha2k is going to need to loop through that array anyway if he/she wants it to print out all the data. It might be easier, or at least more readable, to return json_encode($data), then in your javascript loop with for(key in parsedText){

Comment: @khartnett By the way, my original comment was meant more for the OP, I had already upvoted your answer before that...

Answer (score 0):

You need to use valid JSON, strings are always surrounded with double-quotes and object keys are also surrounded by double-quotes. So your JSON string that is served up by PHP should read as follows:

```
[{"objectValue":"Name","textObject":"Someone"},{"objectValue":"Surname","textObject":"Somebody"}]
```

There's a good online reference for [JSON structure](http://www.json.org/) that you might want to give a read.